# How to get Ajax function for onkeyup event in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have 2 files in `VIEW` folder: `addcustomer.php` and `phoneError.php`.

**addcustomer.php**

```
<input  type="text" id="textHint" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" name="phone" placeholder="1235558888">
<span id="txtHint"></span>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function showHint(str) {
        var base_url = <?php echo base_url(); ?>
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        else {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };

            // Get $p from phoneError.php
            (xmlhttp.open("GET", "phoneError.php?p=" + str, true));
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>

<input  type="text" id="textHint" onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" name="phone" placeholder="1235558888">
<span id="txtHint"></span>
```

**phoneError.php**

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') || exit('No direct script access allowed');

    $p = $_REQUEST['p']; // required

    $string_exp = "/^[0-9]{3}[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4}$/";


    if ($p == !preg_match($string_exp, $p)) {
        echo $error_message .= '<span style="color:red">Oops! The Phone you entered     does not appear to be valid.</span>';
    }
 ?>
```

I want to add Ajax function into `onkeyup` event in addcustomer form to check valid phone number entered. I called addcustomer method and also loaded `phoneError` in Controller but did not work. I am not sure I put correct url for  `xmlhttp.open "GET"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if your are using Codeigniter you should know basic structure of it.
So put php code in same controller file which loads your view and name it as

```
public function phoneError(){
    // your php code..
}
```

In html side

change id of span as id should be unique in same page.

Replace

`<span id="txtHint"></span>`

with this

```
<span id="txtResult"></span>
```

In input tag remove onKeyUp attr.
So replace with this

```
<input type="text" id="textHint" name="phone" placeholder="1235558888">
```

And some change in js

So basically your view file is as

addCustomer.php

```
<input  type="text" id="textHint"  name="phone" placeholder="1235558888" value="">
        <span id="txtResult"></span>

        <script type="text/javascript" >
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#textHint").keyup(function () {
                        var str = $(this).val();
                        $.get("http://localhost/sitename/controllername/phoneError?p=" + str, function (data) {
                            $("#txtResult").html(data);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Now try with this.

Comment: do I load phoneError in controller?
public function phoneError(){
    this->load->view('customer/phoneError');
}

In ht

Comment: no, there is no need to load any view in `public function phoneError()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jquery code for your purpose. This code do exactly same that you want.

```
$("#textHint").keyup(function () {
    $.get("phoneError.php?p=" + $(this).val(), function (data) {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: you need to correct get url. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: did not work :(   onKeyUp="showHint(this.value)" how i change this ? I put phoneError.php in view folder same with addcustomer is that correct url?

Comment: no, you need to add one method (say phoneError) in your current controller. And you need to put your code in this method. Now you are able to access this like site_url + 'controllerName/phoneError'.

Comment: so I need to remove jquery code in view and add it in phoneError method in Controller ?

Comment: remove onKeyUp attribute from element. Use my script code instead of yours. And controller method that i suggest in earlier comment. Can you give me controller name?

Comment: My controller: Customer

Should I add method in controller like this??
public phoneError(){
$("#textHint").keyup(function () {
    $.get("phoneError.php?p=" + $(this).val(), function (data) {
        $("#txtHint").html(data);
    });
});
}

Comment: @Jenny Check my answer